# How to split a string by whitespaces except between words using a regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, split

I'm using `split` to separate this string:

```
@output = "5 490 'Msci Italy' 'Msci Germany' 'Msci France' 'Msci Spain' 'Msci Emu' '05/01/2007' '12/01/2007' '19/01/2007' '26/01/2007' '02/02/2007' 0.2000 0.1996 0.1994 0.2001 0.1983"
```

I want to obtain an array in this form:

```
@array_output = ["5", "490", "'Msci Italy'", "'Msci Germany'", "'Msci France'", "'Msci Spain'", "'Msci Emu'", "'05/01/2007'", "'12/01/2007'", "'19/01/2007'", "'26/01/2007'", "'02/02/2007'", "0.2000", "0.1996", "0.1994", "0.2001", "0.1983"]
```

I tried using:

```
@array_output = @output.split(/\s(?!\w)|\s(?=\d)/)
```

This works on Rubular but when I try to  print `<%= @array_output[0] %>`, or any other index, into a html.erb page in Rails then I obtain nothing.

The `@output` string could have different lenght, this is only a small sample to show all possible formats. Order of formats is always the same tough.

I initialized `@array_output` using `@array_output = Array.new` but it doesn't affect the result.

I also tried `scan` instead of `split` but nothing changed too.

What's wrong?

Comment: I just tried you code and it works ok for me. Can you provide more details about your code. A small correction: In your expected result the `'Msci Spain'`-value is missing.

Comment: Please be more diligent with your formatting. It helps us help you, and others understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes @knut, sorry, I forgot `'Msci Spain'` in the expected result. I edited to correct it, thanks. Thanks @the Tin Man for correcting my post to improve formatting, I'm rather new on StackOverflow.

Comment: Will the format/order of values in `@array_output` ever vary or are those fields fixed?

Comment: @the Tin Man I edited the question to include such information, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with `CSV` and it worked except the quotes are missing. If it's okay to you then

```
require 'csv'

@output = "5 490 'Msci Italy' 'Msci Germany' 'Msci France' 'Msci Spain' 'Msci Emu' '05/01/2007' '12/01/2007' '19/01/2007' '26/01/2007' '02/02/2007' 0.2000 0.1996 0.1994 0.2001 0.1983"

@array_output = CSV.parse_line(@output, col_sep: " ", quote_char: "'")
#=> ["5", "490", "Msci Italy", "Msci Germany", "Msci France", "Msci Spain", "Msci Emu", "05/01/2007", "12/01/2007", "19/01/2007", "26/01/2007", "02/02/2007", "0.2000", "0.1996", "0.1994", "0.2001", "0.1983"]
```

Comment: Quotes missing are also ok.
I tried this one but it fill the array only in the index 0. So `@array_output[0]` gives me 5 but `@array_output[1]` or other indexes give me nothing. I also used `@array_output = Array.new` because I feared `@array_output` was a variable and not an array but nothing change.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe there's something wrong in other places, for example, the 2 `@array_output` actually are not the same object.

Comment: If I use `split()` it fills the array more than in the 0 index (tough incorrectly splitting between words too). Maybe there's something wrong in parse_line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Negative Look Behind and Negative Look Ahead:

`/(?<![a-zA-z])\s+(?![a-zA-z])/`

```
output = "5 490 'Msci Italy' 'Msci Germany' 'Msci France' 'Msci Spain' 'Msci Emu' '05/01/2007' '12/01/2007' '19/01/2007' '26/01/2007' '02/02/2007' 0.2000 0.1996 0.1994 0.2001 0.1983"

output.split(/(?<![a-zA-z])\s+(?![a-zA-z])/).each { |e| puts e }
```

Ouput:

```
5
490
'Msci Italy'
'Msci Germany'
'Msci France'
'Msci Spain'
'Msci Emu'
'05/01/2007'
'12/01/2007'
'19/01/2007'
'26/01/2007'
'02/02/2007'
0.2000
0.1996
0.1994
0.2001
0.1983
```

Let's break down this Regex:

`(?<![a-zA-z])` That's the negative look behind

`\s+` One or more white spaces

`(?![a-zA-z])` Tha's the negative look ahead

Answer (score -1):

First off, `split` isn't the right tool, and defining a pattern for `split` to use that could result in the right output would be a nightmare. Instead, here's how I'd go about breaking it down:

```
regex = /
(\d+)
\s+
(\d+)
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
('[^']+')
\s+
([\d.]+)
\s+
([\d.]+)
\s+
([\d.]+)
\s+
([\d.]+)
\s+
([\d.]+)
/x
mat = regex.match("5 490 'Msci Italy' 'Msci Germany' 'Msci France' 'Msci Spain' 'Msci Emu' '05/01/2007' '12/01/2007' '19/01/2007' '26/01/2007' '02/02/2007' 0.2000 0.1996 0.1994 0.2001 0.1983")
```

Which results in:

```
require 'ap'

ap mat.captures 

# >> [
# >>   [ 0] "5",
# >>   [ 1] "490",
# >>   [ 2] "'Msci Italy'",
# >>   [ 3] "'Msci Germany'",
# >>   [ 4] "'Msci France'",
# >>   [ 5] "'Msci Spain'",
# >>   [ 6] "'Msci Emu'",
# >>   [ 7] "'05/01/2007'",
# >>   [ 8] "'12/01/2007'",
# >>   [ 9] "'19/01/2007'",
# >>   [10] "'26/01/2007'",
# >>   [11] "'02/02/2007'",
# >>   [12] "0.2000",
# >>   [13] "0.1996",
# >>   [14] "0.1994",
# >>   [15] "0.2001",
# >>   [16] "0.1983"
# >> ]
```

Doing a bit of rearranging for readability:

```
regex = /
(\d+) \s+

(\d+) \s+

('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+

('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+
('[^']+') \s+

([\d.]+) \s+
([\d.]+) \s+
([\d.]+) \s+
([\d.]+) \s+
([\d.]+)
/x
mat = regex.match("5 490 'Msci Italy' 'Msci Germany' 'Msci France' 'Msci Spain' 'Msci Emu' '05/01/2007' '12/01/2007' '19/01/2007' '26/01/2007' '02/02/2007' 0.2000 0.1996 0.1994 0.2001 0.1983")

require 'ap'

ap mat.captures
```

We still get:

```
# >> [
# >>   [ 0] "5",
# >>   [ 1] "490",
# >>   [ 2] "'Msci Italy'",
# >>   [ 3] "'Msci Germany'",
# >>   [ 4] "'Msci France'",
# >>   [ 5] "'Msci Spain'",
# >>   [ 6] "'Msci Emu'",
# >>   [ 7] "'05/01/2007'",
# >>   [ 8] "'12/01/2007'",
# >>   [ 9] "'19/01/2007'",
# >>   [10] "'26/01/2007'",
# >>   [11] "'02/02/2007'",
# >>   [12] "0.2000",
# >>   [13] "0.1996",
# >>   [14] "0.1994",
# >>   [15] "0.2001",
# >>   [16] "0.1983"
# >> ]
```

Even that is a bit messy, so you'll find in complex patterns, or code that needs to be easily maintained and understandable, that they've broken the pattern generation down into small steps and let the language handle building the complex pattern, something like this:

```
SINGLE_QUOTED_PATTERN = "('[^']+')"
INTEGER_PATTERN = '(\d+)'
FLOAT_PATTERN = '([\d.]+)'
WHITE_SPACE_PATTERN = '\s+'

REGEX_STRING = [
  [INTEGER_PATTERN] * 2,
  [SINGLE_QUOTED_PATTERN] * 10,
  [FLOAT_PATTERN] * 5
].flatten.join(WHITE_SPACE_PATTERN) 

REGEX = /#{REGEX_STRING}/
# => /(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+('[^']+')\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)/

data = "5 490 'Msci Italy' 'Msci Germany' 'Msci France' 'Msci Spain' 'Msci Emu' '05/01/2007' '12/01/2007' '19/01/2007' '26/01/2007' '02/02/2007' 0.2000 0.1996 0.1994 0.2001 0.1983"

mat = REGEX.match(data)
```

Which, again, results in:

```
require 'ap'

ap mat.captures 

# >> [
# >>   [ 0] "5",
# >>   [ 1] "490",
# >>   [ 2] "'Msci Italy'",
# >>   [ 3] "'Msci Germany'",
# >>   [ 4] "'Msci France'",
# >>   [ 5] "'Msci Spain'",
# >>   [ 6] "'Msci Emu'",
# >>   [ 7] "'05/01/2007'",
# >>   [ 8] "'12/01/2007'",
# >>   [ 9] "'19/01/2007'",
# >>   [10] "'26/01/2007'",
# >>   [11] "'02/02/2007'",
# >>   [12] "0.2000",
# >>   [13] "0.1996",
# >>   [14] "0.1994",
# >>   [15] "0.2001",
# >>   [16] "0.1983"
# >> ]
```

Comment: Nowhere in your question did you say that. When asking, we expect you to provide everything we need to know. "[mcve]". If the data is variable, then you're best off using CSV and changing your separator to spaces, and accept the fact you won't get the wrapping single-quotes.

Comment: To clarify for readers: I deleted my previous comment where I stated I couldn't accept fixed solution because I saw a new edit on the answer that seemed to represent a more flexible solution. In the meantime the user replied to my deleted comment.

Comment: If the order/format of the output string is always the same, then the above solutions will work. Length of fields won't matter, only that they occur in the specified order. After asking a question it's important to wait several hours at a minimum. SO is a global site so you want to allow time for those around the world to offer help and formulate their answers. It takes time to write a detailed/educational answer and there often are multiple edits in the process.